# Display multiple single values in a single column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have several (about 4) single values returned by `datepart()` such as:

```
DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, +3, GETDATE()))
DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, +5, GETDATE()))
```

And I want to display them in a column, let's name it `col1`. I am thinking about doing something like this:

```
with col1 as (
    -- put these values in a column
)
select * from col1
```

How do I achieve this? Any approach is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, +3, GETDATE())) as col1
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, +5, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question, but:

If you're just looking to append those values into one column you can just do it something like this:

```
SELECT 
  DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, +3, GETDATE())) + ' - ' + DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, +5, GETDATE()))
AS Col1
```

Make sure, though, that you're not really looking for functionality that [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) or [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) can do for you.

EDIT: Or, if you are looking to list the values as separate rows in a column then yes, gofr1 has the answer for you!